# Does AnimationDidStop have an animationDidStart counterpart for implicit animations?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am doing an implicit animation, and the following function gets called when it's done:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context;
```

Is there a similar function that will get called when an implicit animation begins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
- (void)animationWillStart:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context;
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that's what it was, but it's not getting called for some reason :(